# 複数の画像を一つのファイル選択ダイアログでアップロードするには？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

rails4で複数の画像を一つのファイルで実装しようとしているのですが、できない状態になっています。もし、わかる方がいらしたら、どうぞ教えていただけたら、嬉しいです。

```js
model

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploaders :images, ImageUploader
  serialize :images, JSON
end
```

```css
controller

params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body, {images: []})
```

```html
html

<%= form.file_field :images, multiple: true %>
```

複数のファイル
[image: 複数のファイル]
一つのファイル

[image: 一つのファイル]

Comment: html に `html: { multipart: true }` が必要とかではないですか？ [Rails 4 multiple image or file upload using carrierwave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31227021/9014308), あるいは不要かもですが。[Rails4 で form_for が multipart にならない](https://qiita.com/YumaInaura/items/99c1c44bfe91622b18b6)

Comment: form_tagでも実装可能ですか？

Comment: 出来るというか必須らしいです。[form_tagでファイルアップロード時はmultipart:trueを省略しない Rails4](http://source.hatenadiary.jp/entry/2014/03/21/143914)

Comment: 度々ありがとうございます。imageカラムのjsonではなく、stringでも、この機能は実装することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: 例えば、文字列を配列で受け取る [Ruby on Rails: Submitting an array in a form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3089849/9014308), 画像と紐づけられた文字列？配列？ [How to Build HTML Inputs to Submit an Array of Hashes with a Rails Form Tag that Work with Strong Params](https://medium.com/@dmccoy/how-to-build-html-inputs-to-submit-an-array-of-hashes-with-a-rails-form-tag-that-work-with-strong-f70a6c03d78e), あたりでしょうか。まとまったのはこれですかね [Action View フォームヘルパー](https://railsguides.jp/form_helpers.html)